# How to interpret the results of robustness checking?

Tags: r, model, statistics, regression, robustness

I am attempting to perform a comparative study, in which I conducted four regression models (2x2) and wanted to compare different functions of ivs to dvs. I wonder how to do robustness checking in this case and what is a robust results? Should all the ivs(I have 14 ivs) be consistent in the robustness checking results?

Comment: Welcome to SO, ke Chen! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: And as a side note, this appears like it might be more about the theory and/or math of the problem, not programming per se. If that's the case, I suggest this would be more appropriate at [stats.se]. (The need for reproducibility may not be as strict there as here, but you really need to augment the question with _something_.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.